# Having multiple radiobuttonlist in a form in yii

Tags: yii, model, radiobuttonlist

I have a model named "Myform" and each Myform has 25 questions(questions themselfs does not store in database).Answer for each question store in another table ( table ), so there is one to many relations between form and answers. I want to show each question in my form as an radiobuttonlist and then save or retrieve data to/from database. I know I can show a radiobutton like this:

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'question', array('1'=>'option1 ', '2'=>'option 2 ', '3'=>'option3 ')); ?>
```

and to set its value do this:

```
$model->question='1';
```

now what should I do to show/save other questions? cause for second, third questions I need something like question2 ,question3 in my second parameter which actually des not exists in the model.

Comment: why are you using a separate model? if you use the model of your db table, you can simply use the different columns as form field names...

Comment: do you mean its better to add 25 fields as answer in the first table?

Comment: it all depends on the structure of your table and the way you'd want to store information from the form... difficult to say what the best practice should be without having an inderstanding of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save 25 answers for each model you need 25 columns in your answers table, where each row represents a record for the the 25 answers.

Your table should have columns id, name (or any other info), answer1, answer2, answer3, and so on.

When you receive the answers you should save it using

```
$answerModel->answer1 = $_POST['QuestionForm']['question1'];
$answerModel->answer2 = $_POST['QuestionForm']['question2'];
$answerModel->answer3 = $_POST['QuestionForm']['question3'];
... so on ...
```